# data grabbing/restructuring speed

Tags: php, mysql

This question might be flagged as too broad or opinion-based, but I take the risk...

I have a REST-API in php that gets all data from a mysql table, that also includes 'hasMany' fields. Let's call them a 'post' hasMany 'comments'.

Right now I'm doing ONE select with a LEFT JOIN on comments, then walk through the results to restructure the output to

```
{ "posts": [
    {"id": 1,
     "comments": [1,2,3] 
    },
    ....
]}
```

All is fine until I have more than one hasMany-field, because then the refacturing gets complicated (now produces double entries) and I would need to loop through the result (not manually, but still with built in functions) several times.

So I thought about refacturing my code to:
1. select the actual item ('post')
2. select all hasMany fields ('comments', 'anythingelse',...) and add the results.
which of course produces loads of action on my db.

*So my question is* if anybody has a simple answer like 'better grab all the data in one go from a database and do the work in php' or the opposite.

Yes, I could do benchmarks myself. But fist - to be honest I would like to avoid all the reprogramming just to find out it's slower - second i don't know if my benchmark would remain the same on an optimized (and linux) production machine (right now I'm developing on easyPhp on windows).

*Some info: 
The 'post' table could result in some hundred records, same as the hasMany each. But combined with some hasMany fields it could result in a recordset (with the first aproach) of several thousands.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `IN (…)` operator.

First, get the relevant posts on their own:

```
SELECT […stuff…] FROM posts WHERE […conditions…]
```

Then take the list of post IDs from the results you get there and substitute the whole list into a set of queries of the form:

```
SELECT […stuff…] FROM comments WHERE post_id IN (1, 2, 3 […etc…])
SELECT […stuff…] FROM anythingelse WHERE post_id IN (1, 2, 3 […etc…])
```

Running one query per dependent table is fine. It's not significantly more expensive than running a single JOINed query; in fact, it may be less expensive, as there's no duplication of the fields from the parent table.

Make sure the `post_id` column is indexed on the subtables, of course.

Comment: thank you, your _edit_ was the most important part for me!

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative that I can think of would be along the lines of:

```
$posts = $dbh->prepare('SELECT [fields] FROM posts WHERE [conditions]')->
  execute([...])->
  fetchAll();

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?');
for($i=0; $i<count($posts); $i++) {
  $stmt->execute($posts[$i]['id']);
  $posts[$i]['comments'] = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

You need to decide if the work/overhead tradeoff between dealing "duplicate" data as a result of the join is more or less than separately retrieving the comments for each post.

Chance are if you were using an ORM something along the lines of the above would be happening automagically.

Comment: the 'you need to decide' was the actual question... Thanks anyway!

Comment: All of that depends on the nature of your application, your data, and your systems architecture. No one can benchmark your particular environment other than you.

Comment: Yes, I know that this question was very broad. You both gave me kind the same path which I'll benchmark then in my enviroment. I just needed an idea if so many sql queries is an idiotic approach in first place... _before_ coding  and benchmarking it.